# Transpose Range Variable

Tags: vba, excel

I am having issues with transposing a Range variable from a 4x1 format to 1x4 format (4 rows)

I searched everywhere yet I can't seem to find anything that works.

Here is what I tried:

```
Function test(periodcol2 As Range, ratecol2 As Range, X As Range)
    Dim periodcol As Range
    Dim ratecol As Range

If periodcol2.Columns.Count > 1 Then
    periodcol.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(periodcol2)
    ratecol.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ratecol2)
End If
```

Crashes on the Value assignment.

```
If periodcol2.Columns.Count > 1 Then
    Set periodcol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(periodcol2)
    Set ratecol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ratecol2)

End If
```

Same result.

EDIT: This doesn't work either, instead it makes periodcol content 'empty' as shown by excel tooltip

```
Dim periodcol As Variant
Dim ratecol As Variant

If periodcol2.Columns.Count > 1 Then
    periodcol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(periodcol2)
    ratecol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ratecol2)
Else
```

EDIT2: rate_count & period_count are equal to 0 at the end of this code.

```
Function TEST(periodcol2 As Range, ratecol2 As Range, X As Range)
Dim periodcol As Variant
Dim ratecol As Variant

If periodcol2.Columns.Count > 1 Then
    periodcol = Application.Transpose(periodcol2)
    ratecol = Application.Transpose(ratecol2)
Else

    Set periodcol = periodcol2
    Set ratecol = ratecol2
End If



Dim period_count As Integer
Dim rate_count As Integer
period_count = periodcol.Rows.Count
rate_count = ratecol.Rows.Count
```

Note: I don't want to paste the values anywhere, just keep them in the code.

Comment: When you're transposing values from a range you're not working with Ranges but with arrays. So you declare (eg) `periodcol` as Variant and don't use `Set` to assign the return value from `Transpose`

Comment: See edit, making them variants yields different result (no crash) but still doesn't work

Comment: edited my post, those are inputs into the function, if function detects more columns then one, it needs to transpose it.

Comment: How exactly are you testing `periodcol`? Check the Locals window as a tooltip can't show you the values of an array.

Comment: it actually says periodcol=Empty in the yellow excel tooltip, also `periodcol.Rows.Count` returns 0

Comment: You should set `periodcol` to a range of the proper size to hold the result of the transpose operation before you try to assign a value to it. As it is, it is an unitialized variable.

Comment: can I set `periodcol` to the size of periodcol2 (just opposite row and col?)

Comment: "Note: I don't want to paste the values anywhere, just keep them in the code" - variants don't have "rows" or "columns", so if you want to work with data in-memory you need to think in terms of arrays and not ranges.

Comment: Decide what *location* you want the transposed values to be in. If you don't want the values to be in the spreadsheet -- follow Tim William's advice and assign it to a variant.

Comment: assigning to a Variant does not work - see the edit

Comment: Are you sure that `ratecol2` isn't empty? I just tested it and it is completely non-problematic to assign the transpose of a non-empty range to a variant variable, the result being an array stored in the variant.

Comment: There is, however, a limit to the *size* of the array that can be transposed (at least in some versions of Excel) -- perhaps that is what you are running into.

Comment: no, the input ranges I'm testing are 1x4 and 4x1. 100% sure they are not empty. I'm trying to transpose 4 cols, 1 row to 4 rows

Comment: When you step through code in the debugger, `ratecol2` will still display as `Empty` on mouse hover when that line is the highlighted line. -- you have to go to the next step to see how executing that line changes the contents of the variables. Also -- you should probably use the Locals Window rather than mouse hover if you really want to see what's going on.

Comment: See edit2, `rate_count` and `period_count` are equal to 0 at the end of the code.

Comment: `Ubound` works but then I lose the ability to refer to elements as ratecol(1) and need to do ratecol(1,1) instead ?

Comment: Yes -- you need to use `ratecol(1,1)` -- one of the great annoyances of Excel VBA is that `nx1` ranges become `1 to n, 1 to 1` arrays when you assign them to a variant

Comment: See the edit in my answer for getting a 1-D array.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim rng As Range, arr, arr2

    Set rng = Range("A1:D1") 'contents 1,2,3,4

    If rng.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        arr = Application.Transpose(rng.Value)
        'arr is now a 2-d array (1 to 4, 1 to 1)
        Debug.Print arr(1, 1), arr(2, 1), arr(3, 1), arr(4, 1)
         ' >>>   1 2 3 4

        'EDIT: if you want a 1-D array
        arr2 = Application.Transpose(arr)
        Debug.Print arr2(1), arr2(2), arr2(3), arr2(4)

    End If


End Sub
```